# Post to Page's Wall from Tab trough FB.ui

Tags: javascript, facebook, feed, fb.ui

hopefully somebody can help me, because I'm a bit confused and not sure if it's even possible what I'm trying to do.

My goal is to let users/fans of a Page post info to the Page's Wall from within a Tab.
I'm using the `FB.ui` javascript call with the `feed` method:

```
FB.ui({
    method: 'feed',
    to: app_id,
    caption: 'Test',
    description: 'Test message....'
}, function (response) {
    console.log(response);
});
```

This however only works for Page admins. Is there a way to get this working for non-admins as well? (Users are allowed to post to the page's Wall, and are able to do so trough the default Facebook interface).

All users have the related App installed, but have only given basic auth. (No extended permissions to post on their behalf)

Of course I could post a message trough the App on behalf of the Page, but I would like to have the users do the posting.

Please note, I'm not forcing any user to make the post, it's merely a convenience feature.